# Confirm message on Laravel Submit Button

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel

I want to create a Confirm message if the user klicks on my submit button. I've created the submit button with the Laravel Form package. Well, I don't really work with javascript and haven't found an answer for that.

Thats my submit Form:

```
{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
```

I tried something like this:

```
<script>

  function ConfirmDelete()
  {
  var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
  if (x)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
  }

</script>

{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'onsubmit' => 'return ConfirmDelete()']) !!}
```

But this haven't worked. Can anyone help me there?

Comment: Do you see any error in `console` ? Care to elaborate _haven't worked_!

Comment: no everything seems fine

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? Also share the parsed `HTML`

Comment: Problem Solved! look into my question update :)

Comment: But is there a way to change the style of the confirm box? it's still this old html box. Maybe a bootstrap way?

Comment: If you have found an answer to your question, I guess, you should add it as an answer. Community will find it helpful and structured.

Comment: I will.. but as I see my problem is still there... the confirmation comes and deletes the thread, the problem is, if I'm pressing on cancel, it also deletes my thread

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using inline-event `onsubmit` you could add an extra class `test-form` then attach `submit` event to it in js code.

**Adding class :**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['Test\\TestController@destroy', $thread->id], 'method' =>
    'delete', 'class' => 'test-form' ]) !!}
```

**Attaching submit event :**

```
$('.test-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?") ) {
        $(this).submit();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.